# GTFS SQL Query for Indirect Route

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I need to write a query to find routes/trips between two stops in GTFS data structure, I have migrated all the csv data to mysql tables. Here is the sample data for stop_times.txt

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign,shape_dist_traveled
170309010001S10,12:24:00,12:24:00,10000871,1,MRT SG BULOH - HOSPITAL SG BULOH,0.00688
170309010001S10,12:28:32,12:28:32,10000872,2,MRT SG BULOH - HOSPITAL SG BULOH,1.249023
170309010001S10,12:29:57,12:29:57,10002386,3,MRT SG BULOH - HOSPITAL SG BULOH,1.595181
170309010001S10,12:31:58,12:31:58,10000874,4,MRT SG BULOH - HOSPITAL SG BULOH,2.113874
170309010001S10,12:33:45,12:33:45,10000875,5,MRT SG BULOH - HOSPITAL SG BULOH,2.56561
```

I am not able to make a query that will return to me all the trips for an indirect route, any help will really appreciated.

Comment: if you need to find paths where they start and end on a different route, you're best served by looking at OpenTripPlanner: http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Trip.Id and Route.Id Beteween two stops.

```
select StopTimes.TripId , Trips.RouteId
from StopTimes 
join Trips on (Trips.Id = StopTimes.TripId)
Where TripId in 
(
    select StopTimes.TripId
    from StopTimes
    Where StopTimes.StopId = FirstStopId
) 
And StopTimes.StopId = SecondStopId
```

Keep in mind, to create an index on StopTimes.TripId.